# How to create Pandas Dataframe from lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I have four lists like this:

```
A = ['column_1',
     'column_2',
     'column_3']

B = ['string_1',
     'string_2',
     'string_3']

numA = [1,2,3]
numB = [4,5,6]
```

Is there is way to make Dataframe which as column names will take both lists `A` and `B` and as an row both lists `numA` and `numB`? So it will look like this:

```
column_1    column_2    column_3    string_1    string_2    string_3
    1           2           3           4           5           6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.DataFrame([numA+numB], columns=A+B)
```

Comment: Works. Thank you! :)